# Symfony2 White screen app.php : ProxyFactory.php

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I've got a white screen in app.php but not in app_dev.php
On Apache logs :

> PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required
>   '[...]app/cache/prod/doctrine/orm/Proxies\_*CG*_SdzForumBundleEntityCategory.php'
>   (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in
>   [...]\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Proxy\ProxyFactory.php
>   on line 92

I already tried:

- cache:clear --env=prod
- cache:clear --env=prod --no-warmup
- cache:warmup --env=prod
- composer.phar update
- chmod 777 -R app/cache app/logs web/js web/bundles web/css
- doctrine:schema:update --force

The problem begin when I tried to move a vendor bundle into my sources because it is not updated by developpers:
https://github.com/Herzult/HerzultForumBundle

I think there is many ways to get informations from database, and this forum bundle uses one way that I do not master.

Here are some code

**config.yml**

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        auto_mapping: true
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        proxy_namespace: Proxies
        proxy_dir: %kernel.cache_dir%/doctrine/orm/Proxies
        default_entity_manager: default
        metadata_cache_driver: array
        query_cache_driver: array
        result_cache_driver: array
```

**Entity/Category.php**

```
namespace Sdz\ForumBundle\Entity;

use Sdz\ForumBundle\Model\Category as BaseCategory;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="sdz_forum_category")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Sdz\ForumBundle\Entity\CategoryRepository")
 */
class Category extends BaseCategory
{
```

**Entity/CategoryRepository.php**

```
namespace Sdz\ForumBundle\Entity;

use Sdz\ForumBundle\Model\CategoryRepositoryInterface;
use Sdz\ForumBundle\Entity\ObjectRepository;

class CategoryRepository extends ObjectRepository implements CategoryRepositoryInterface
{
```

**Resources/config/orm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

    <services>
        <!-- Object Manager Service -->
        <service id="herzult_forum.object_manager" alias="doctrine.orm.entity_manager" />
    </services>

</container>
```

**model.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

    <services>
        <!-- [...] -->

        <!-- Topic Repository Service -->
        <service id="herzult_forum.repository.topic" class="Sdz\ForumBundle\Model\TopicRepositoryInterface" factory-service="herzult_forum.object_manager" factory-method="getRepository">
            <argument type="string">%herzult_forum.model.topic.class%</argument>
        </service>

        <!-- [...] -->
    </services>

</container>
```

**DefaultController.php**

```
//Problem line
$topics     = $this->get('herzult_forum.repository.topic')->findBy(array(), array('pulledAt' => 'desc'), 10);
```

I hope that someone can help me. Thanks a lot at least for reading :)

Comment: it's something very simple: try app/console cache:clear --no-warmup --env=prod, or also composer create a autoloader file so you need do composer update maybe

Comment: Same problem with **app/console cache:clear --no-warmup --env=prod** or **composer.phar update**

Comment: Topic solved in force mode (I had to re-make the bundle class by class).

Comment: After `app/console cache:clear --no-warmup --env=prod` I had to warmup the cache:  `app/console cache:warmup --env=prod`. Which regenerate the doctrine proxy classes.